# filling a reportviewer via code

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-reporting

We are working on a web-app that will show a report based upon a variable chosen by the user. My boss has a similar web-app that he has had me base mine off of. I have checked and my Reportviewer is set up just like his, as well as my SqlDataSource seems to be set up similarly also. his C# code is this:

```
var Class_Connection = new SQL_Connection();
            Class_Connection.cnn.Close();
            Class_Connection.cnn.Open();

            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Assigned, FirstName, LastName, Description, Resolved" +
                                     " FROM TT WHERE Received >= DATEADD(day,-"+ NumberOfDays +", GETDATE())", Class_Connection.cnn);

            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

            var source = new ReportDataSource("DataSetAllTTByLastWeek", dt);

            RV_Main.Visible = true;
            RV_Main.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            RV_Main.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/CCD/TT/Reports/AllTTByLastWeek.rdlc");
            RV_Main.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
            RV_Main.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Where Mine is this:

```
var Class_Connection = new SQL_Connection();
            Class_Connection.cnn.Close();
            Class_Connection.cnn.Open();

            var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT PO.PO_Num, PO.Supplier, PO.DateRequired, PO.DateRecv, PO.Terms, PO.Freight, PO.FOB, Beam.Tag, Beam.Quantity, Beam.ReceiverNumber, Beam.DeliveredBy, Beam.ReceivedBy, Beam.PackingNo, BeamType.Description From PO PO, Beam Beam,BeamType BeamType Where BeamType.Type = Beam.Type and Beam.PoNum = PO.PO_Num and Beam.Beamcode = BeamType.Beamcode and Beam.receivernumber = " + ReceiverNumber + " Order By BeamType.Description ASC, Beam.Quantity Asc", Class_Connection.cnn);

            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

            var source = new ReportDataSource("BeamReports", dt);

            rvLumberReport.Visible = true;
            rvLumberReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            rvLumberReport.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/CCD/Main/Reports/BeamReport.rdlc");
            rvLumberReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
            rvLumberReport.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

When i run his code everything works correctly, however when i run mine, it does not seem to show the report in the viewer. right now it's just a label that says testing. am i missing something stupid simple or could i have borked something?

EDIT: the first set of code only seems to work on it's original page, but will not work on the second page. the second set of code will not work in the first page. I have done my best to ensure that all controls are configured to as close to the originals as i can tell.

EDIT2: I created a new page within the project and used this code to make a report that worked perfectly. my guess is that the issue has to be within the ASP or C# code related the this page. the question at this point is: "how do i figure out where the issue is?"

Comment: Why are you closing the connection, then opening it right afterwards? Why is your code not wrapped in appropriate using statements?

Comment: Why are you not using parameterized queries? You're vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: The using statements are not there due to the sheer size of the code page. i'm not using parameterized queries because i'm doing this the way the boss told me to. this is the C# behind the ASP and there are no text based inputs, just radios and drop-down lists. but mainly, i'm doing it this way because the boss said to do it this way.

Comment: You're thinking of the wrong using statements. When you're dealing with unmanaged resources, objects implement IDisposable interface and need to be specially handled. You can read more about that [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). Whether they're text or radio button or drop down list doesn't matter, it's still vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Your boss wrote vulnerable and brittle code. Fix it up and explain to him why you fixed it.